# JS creating babel plugin: how to get arguments of anonymous function

Tags: javascript, plugins, babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree, anonymous-function

I am trying to create a plugin which detects execution of function while it transpiles and returns arguments of it

For example:

code:

```
testFN("hello");
testFN("world");
```

would return while babel transpiling:

```
hello
world
```

I created a babel plugin that can detect that function and output its parameters, but I cannot find arguments inside it

So it currently looks like this

```
module.exports = function ({ types: t }) {
  return {
    visitor: {
      Identifier(path) {
        if (path.node.name === 'testFN') {
          console.log(path.node);
        }
      },
    },
  };
};
```

It outputs:

```
Node {
  type: 'Identifier',
  start: 753,
  end: 759,
  loc:
   SourceLocation {
     start: Position { line: 19, column: 8 },
     end: Position { line: 19, column: 14 },
     identifierName: 'testFN' },
  name: 'testFN' }
Node {
  type: 'Identifier',
  start: 830,
  end: 836,
  loc:
   SourceLocation {
     start: Position { line: 23, column: 2 },
     end: Position { line: 23, column: 8 },
     identifierName: 'testFN' },
  name: 'testFN' }
```

I tried to use AST browser, but it gives different object path which i cannot reach in my babel plugin code https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/763d13950ad0334ac8ea3187464fcdbf/295a8fd8640210cee586444a58445401e8baa690

How can access arguments of my function though babel?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stupid me - tried to get argument trough Identifier. I needed to get it though CallExpression. Cheers

Code:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line func-names
module.exports = function ({ types: t }) {
  return {
    visitor: {
      CallExpression(path, { file }) {
        if (path.node.callee.name === "testFN") {
          console.log(path.node.arguments[)
        }
      },
    },
  };
};
```